# Will Fortran compilers completely remove always false if-blocks when optimizing?

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, fortran90

If i have the following declaration in my program:

```
logical, parameter :: verbose = .false.
```

will adding a bunch of things such as

```
if (verbose) write(*,*) "Information here"
```

affect the performance at all when compiling with "-03"? 
I would hope the compiler would recognize that the blocks are always false and thus completely remove them, so I can feel free to add debug-prints all over. Is this the case?

I guess this may be compiler dependent, but was hoping that there is a single answer for the most common compilers. If not, what is the behavior of gfortran?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That is certainly compiler dependent but something relatively easy for you to check for yourself by looking over the assembler produced by your compiler for a simple test program.  My (educated) guess would be that no self-respecting Fortran compiler would show any performance difference at high optimisation levels for a code with those statements compared with a code without those statements.  But the educated guess of a stranger on the Internet is virtually worthless.

Comment: Dead code elimination is typically one of the first optimizations enabled; in gfortran it's enabled at [`-O`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fdce-794), for instance, and with ifort it's in `-O2`.  I'd be very surprised if that line survived into the executable in any major compiler at -O3, although as @HighPerformanceMark says, this is best determined empirically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the good advice of the commenters above, I tested this myself.
It turns of that with gfortran, even optimization level -O0 appears to completely remove the dead write-blocks.

Comment: +1 for getting your finger out and figuring out the answer for yourself.